# Multiplication of a continuous function with non continuous

Tags: functions

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} e^x e^{-1}  &  ,0 \leq x\leq 1
\\   \lfloor x \rfloor+ 1 & ,1< x < 3 \end{cases}$$
 and $$g(x) = x^2 -ax + b $$ such that $f(x)g(x)$ is continuous in $[0,3)$ then find the ordered pair $(a,b)$

Comment: Just as clarification, you want to find the ordered pair $(a,b)$ such that $f\cdot g$ is continuous in the interval $0\leq x<3$?

Comment: Yah. Exactly that

Comment: I have tried to edit your post, kindly check if this is what you intend to ask. Also, kindly include your thoughts.

Comment: g is always a continuous function but by multiplying it with f at 1 and 2 it no longer remain continuous. Because for f LHL at 1 is 1 while RHL at 1 is 2. In the same way it is for 2. How it can remain continuous function?

Answer (score 3):

Guide:

$$f(1)g(1)=\lim_{x \rightarrow 1^+}f(x)g(x)$$

$$1(1-a+b)=2(1-a+b)$$

Hence we have $1-a+b=0$

Try to do similar trick when the value is $2$ to obtain another constraint and solve for $a$ and $b$.

Remark: Once you are convinced that $g(1)=g(2)=0$, that is $1$ and $2$ are roots of $g$, we can conclude directly that $a=1+2$ and $b=1(2)$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $f$ is not continuous at $1$ and $2$ and $g$ is continuous everywhere, the only way that $fg$ is continuous is that $g(1) = 0$ and $g(2) = 0$

So you get $a=b+1$
and $4-2a+b =0$

In the end, $b=2$ and $a=3$

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it continuous at $x=1$. That is

\begin{align}
   \lim_{x \to 1^-}f(x)g(x) &= \lim_{x \to 1^+}f(x)g(x) \\
   e^{-2}(1-a+b) &= 2(1-a+b) \\
   (e^{-2}-2)(1-a+b) &= 0 \\
   (1-a+b) &= 0 \\
   b &= a-1 \\
\hline
   g(x) &= x^2 + ax +(a-1)
\end{align}